# How is precision and recall calculated in multilabel classification problem where label actual values are between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification

I am going through this amazon [paper](https://assets.amazon.science/73/50/22098aa04c14958b9bd66901fa64/query-attribute-recommendation-at-amazon-search.pdf): Query Attribute Recommendation at Amazon Search. In this paper, a multilabel intent classification model was trained which predicts product type given the query. Labeled queries were constructed using click stream data. Here X was a search query. y was a vector corresponding to each product type where the value of each element in the vector is the ratio of clicks for a given query and product type divided by the total number of clicks for that query.

Please see the screenshot attached to understand the exact statement mentioned regarding the labeled query.

[image]

In such a scenario, values in the y labels would be between 0 and 1. Predicted values would also be between 0 and 1. Authors have reported precision and recall for the multi-label intent classification model [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3523227.3547395).

Question:
How are precision and recall values calculated when values in the y labels lie in the range [0,1] and predicted y label values also lie in the range [0,1]? Is there any threshold mechanism used? Does the threshold differ for each label? Are there any best practices to keep in mind while setting thresholds in such multi-label scenarios?